# Variáveis globais não aparecem mais no Xdebug Client do Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

Estou com um problema com o plugin Xdebug Client. Até umas duas semanas atrás estava perfeito porém agora na aba de Xdebug Context não está mais aparecendo as variáveis globais e todas as variáveis que antes eram exibidas nessa aba.

Estou tendo problemas tanto no Ubuntu 12.04 quanto no Fedora 17. Não se se o problema está relacionado a alguma atualização do Xdebug ou mesmo do plugin Xdebug Client já que não alterei nada no Fedora 17 e parou de exibir. Alguém já teve esse problema ou tem alguma sugestão? Anexo imagens para ilustrar.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Me desculpe @brasofilo, fiz no linux aqui e não prestei atenção a esse detalhe. Já corrigi o formato, obrigado pela atenção ae.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique nas configurações do `xdebug` se o item `xdebug.dump_once` está ativado, se não estiver habilite do seguinte modo:

```
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
```

Para maiores informações consulte a [**documentação**](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings).